# Why do I get wrong Results in my Gekko Optimization when I integrate a switching variable for fix-costs of Components?

Tags: optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem with my optimization program. I am trying to optimize the energy Supply of a Single Family House. To get faster Results I have linearized the Cost-Function on the Components of the System (Heat Pump, Storage (Heat,Electicity), electrical Water heater). The linearization leads to Cost-Functions of the form: `a*x+b` where `x` is the Design-Value for the components (e.g. `P_el_HP_max`) of the energy System. This means that if the design Value of a Component is equal to Zero the "fix-costs" (`b`) still need to be payed. To tell the Program that it only needs to Pay the fix costs if the design-value for the components is greater than Zero, I have added a binary Variable in the Form of `m.if2(-x,1,0)` to see if the "fix-costs" need to be payed. The Objective of the Optimization is to minimize the costs for the Energy System. **The Problem I have is that the solution I get with the `m.if2`-Statements is not the optimal Solution. When I run the Program without the `m.if2` statements for the same time period I get a lower objective even though the "fix-costs" need to be payed so it should be a higher Objective if anything.** I have also tried it with the `m.if3`-Statements and a `m.sign(x)` function, which also doesn't seem to work. It would be much appreciated if someone has an Idea on how i can solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Here is my Code:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timesteps= 100
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
t = np.linspace(0, timesteps-1, timesteps) #Zeit
m.time = t

m.options.SOLVER = 1 
m.options.IMODE = 6 
m.options.NODES = 2 
m.options.REDUCE=3
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1.0e-1',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'objective_convergence_tolerance 1.0e-4',\
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 100',\
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.1']

# Energy Demand

    #1. electricity
    
EL_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.9200000,
 1.4890000,1.4920000,1.1300000,0.64099997,0.58600003,
 0.58399999,0.61000001,0.54900002,0.59500003,0.92699999,
 0.95599997,0.91000003,1.1450000,1.1090000,1.6360000,
 1.4740000,1.4680001,2.6150000,2.1810000,1.2320000,
 1.3700000,0.96899998,1.3220000,1.1880000,0.64399999,
 0.53899997,0.55299997,0.52899998,0.56099999,0.54600000,
 0.80000001,1.1350000,0.70700002,1.1680000,1.0440000,
 2.3160000,1.6420000,2.2370000,2.8870001,1.8550000,
 1.4030000,0.70599997,1.4980000,3.4879999,1.5130000,
 1.4349999,1.3520000,1.0530000,0.51700002,0.55000001,
 0.52800000,0.52999997,0.56199998,0.53700000,0.58999997,
 0.53500003,0.92500001,1.3490000,0.66299999,4.3810000,
 1.0200000,0.79799998,0.77899998,1.0840000,2.1530001,
 3.7449999,5.3490000,1.8710001,2.3610001,0.78799999,
 0.47099999,0.56800002,0.51700002,0.54799998,0.55699998,
 0.51400000,0.56500000,3.2790000,2.2750001,1.2300000,
 0.97899997,0.78200001,1.0140001,0.77800000,0.58099997,
 0.52999997,0.55900002,1.1770000,1.5400000,1.4349999,
 2.0400000,2.2790000,1.6520000,1.6450000,1.2830000,
 0.55800003,0.52499998,0.51899999,0.53799999])
EL_Demand_Arr2=EL_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
EL_Demand_Arr=EL_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

EL_Demand=m.Param(EL_Demand_Arr,name='EL_Demand')
    
    #2. heat
    
H_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.0960000,1.0790000,
 1.1590000,1.1760000,1.6940000,2.2639999,2.1450000,
 2.0769999,2.0720000,2.0300000,1.9069999,1.8810000,
 1.7880000,1.8180000,1.8049999,2.0430000,2.1489999,
 2.1700001,2.1830001,2.1910000,1.9920000,1.5290000,
 1.1810000,1.0400000,1.4310000,1.4110000,1.4700000,
 1.4900000,1.8880000,2.4530001,2.2809999,2.3199999,
 2.2960000,2.3299999,2.1630001,2.1289999,2.0599999,
 2.1090000,2.0940001,2.3450000,2.4380000,2.4679999,
 2.4630001,2.4480000,2.2219999,1.8480000,1.5779999,
 1.4310000,1.5000000,1.4790000,1.5410000,1.5620000,
 1.9790000,2.5720000,2.3910000,2.4319999,2.4070001,
 2.4430001,2.2679999,2.2309999,2.1589999,2.2110000,
 2.1949999,2.4579999,2.5560000,2.5869999,2.5820000,
 2.5660000,2.3290000,1.9380000,1.6540000,1.5000000,
 1.7160000,1.6930000,1.7630000,1.7869999,2.2650001,
 2.9430001,2.7360001,2.7839999,2.7539999,2.7950001,
 2.5950000,2.5539999,2.4710000,2.5300000,2.5120001,
 2.8130000,2.9250000,2.9600000,2.9549999,2.9370000,
 2.6659999,2.2170000,1.8930000,1.7160000,1.7980000,
 1.7670000,1.8789999,1.9160000])
H_Demand_Arr2=H_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
H_Demand_Arr=H_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

H_Demand=m.Param(H_Demand_Arr,name='H_Demand')
    
    #3. Domestic Hot Water
    
DHW_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.7420000,0,0,2.0320001,
 0,0,3.7739999,2.4960001,3.3670001,0,2.4380000,
 1.1030000,0,0,0,3.1350000,2.2060001,0,4.4120002,
 0,0,0,0.87099999,1.5089999,0,0,0,0,0,0.87099999,
 0.81300002,1.1610000,2.5539999,1.6260000,0,0,
 0.63900000,0,3.4830000,2.8450000,2.4960001,
 7.1409998,5.7480001,2.3800001,3.1930001,0,1.1610000,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.6129999,1.9160000,4.2379999,
 0.34799999,5.4569998,0,0,2.8450000,0,0,0,0,0,
 2.4960001,1.6260000,0,2.5539999,0,0,0,0,0,
 1.6260000,0,3.0190001,0,2.8450000,1.1030000,
 2.9030001,0,0,0,0.98699999,0,1.1610000,0.34799999,
 1.3930000,1.2770000,4.4120002,0,0,0,0,1.8580000,
 0,0.98699999])
DHW_Demand_Arr2=DHW_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
DHW_Demand_Arr=DHW_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

DHW_Demand=m.Param(DHW_Demand_Arr,name='TWW_BED')
    
    #4. electricity production from PV
    
PV_P_Arr1=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.057000000,
 0.14399999,0.30500001,0.13600001,0.28900000,0.22000000,
 0.0040000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0.061999999,0.78899997,0.56300002,0.13600001,
 0.052999999,0.017000001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0.037000000,0.098999999,0.15000001,
 0.11200000,0,0.12600000,0.032000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0040000002,0.73600000,1.8250000,
 2.4020000,3.1870000,0.66500002,0.045000002,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
PV_P_Arr2=PV_P_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
PV_P_Arr=PV_P_Arr2[0:timesteps]

PV_P=m.Param(PV_P_Arr,name='PV_P')
    
# Heat Pump "Bit" ist '1' during the Heating Season and '0' outside the heating Season to tell the Promgram that the Heat Pump may only be used during heating Season

HP_Bit_Arr1=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
HP_Bit_Arr=HP_Bit_Arr1[0:timesteps]

HP_Bit=m.Param(HP_Bit_Arr,name='HP_Bit')   


# Battery Storage

B_S = m.SV(0,lb=0) 
B_S.FSTATUS=1
m.fix_initial(B_S,0)

B_S_Load = m.SV(0,lb=0) #Loading Battery
B_S_Recover = m.SV(0,lb=0) #Recover Energy from Batterie

eff_B_S = 0.95 #efficiency Battery


# Heat Storage

H_S = m.SV(0,lb=0) 
H_S.FSTATUS=1
m.fix_initial(H_S,0)

H_S_Load = m.SV(lb=0)    #Loading Heat Storage
H_S_Recover = m.SV(lb=0) #Recover Energy from Heat Storage

eff_H_S = 0.9 #efficiency Heat Storage

#Heat Pump

# Binary Variable for Heat Pump
#  it can either be turned on '1' or off '0'
P_HP_Binary=HP_Bit*m.sos1([0,1])
P_HP_Binary.STATUS = 1 

#Electrical sizing of the Heat Pump

P_el_HP1= m.SV(0,lb=0)
P_el_HP1.FSTATUS=1

#Electrical Water Heater

EH=m.SV(0,lb=0)
EH.FSTATUS=1


# The Power of the Heat Pump multiplied with
#    the Binary Variable gives the actual 
#    Output of the Heat Pump

P_el_HP=m.Intermediate(P_HP_Binary*P_el_HP1)

P_el_HP_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Heat Pump
P_el_HP_max.STATUS=1

H_S_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Heat Storage
H_S_max.STATUS=1

B_S_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Battery
B_S_max.STATUS=1

EH_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Electrical Water Heater
EH_max.STATUS=1


COP_HP=3.5 #COP of the Heat Pump

#Modulating Heat Pump
Q_HP=m.Intermediate(1.4*COP_HP*0.3*P_el_HP_max* \
 P_HP_Binary+(COP_HP*(1-0.3*1.4)/(1-0.3)) \
 *(P_el_HP-0.3*P_el_HP_max*P_HP_Binary)) 

# thermal Energy Output of the Heat Pump
#Q_HP=m.Intermediate(COP_HP*P_el_HP) 

# the objective of this Optimization is to minimize
# the Cost for the Energy-System, since you only 
# Pay for the maximal Value of the Heat Pump, 
# Energy Storage and the electrical Water Heater
# and not for the value at each timestep, I define
# a FV that describes the maximal Value of the Components

#Losses of the Heat Storage
# eps_HS = 0.9 # Heat Storage Efficiancy
# Vol_HS=m.Intermediate((H_S_max*3600)/(1000*4.18*(45-20)))
# Vol_HS_timestep=m.Intermediate((H_S*3600)/(1000*4.18*(45-20)))
# alpha_a=8 #W/m^2K
# s=0.1 #m
# Lamda= 0.03 #W/mK
# r_i=0.3
# r_a=r_i+0.1
# A_Top_Bottom=2*pi*r_a**2
# U_Top_Bottom=(1/((1/alpha_a)+(s/Lamda))) #annahme, keine Konvektion an der Innenseite also alpha_i=0
# U_A_Surface=(((Vol_HS_timestep/(r_i**2))/(((1/Lamda)\
#   *np.log(r_a/r_i))+(1/(alpha_a*r_a)))))

#Q_Losses_HS=m.Intermediate((U_Top_Bottom*A_Top_Bottom*2+U_A_Surface)*(45-20)/1000)

# We have energy Production from PV, there ist a possibility to give Energy thats not needed to the public Grid

I_Excess=m.Var(0,lb=0)

# In Case we have more Demand for Electrical Enery than Production from PV we have the possibility to get Energy from the public Grid

I_feed_out=m.SV(0,lb=0)
I_feed_out.FSTATUS=1

# Volume of the Heat Storage in m^3

Vol_HS=m.Intermediate((H_S_max*3600)/(1000*4.18*(45-20)))

# boundary conditions 
m.Equations([PV_P +I_feed_out + B_S_Recover - P_el_HP - B_S_Load - I_Excess - EH == EL_Demand, #Energy Balance needs to satisfy the Demand
             
             B_S.dt() == B_S_Load - B_S_Recover/eff_B_S, #Loading and Recovery of the Battery
            
             B_S_Load * B_S_Recover == 0, #It is not allowed to Load and Recover at the same Time, at least one of both needs to be equal to '0' at each Timestep
             
              
             Q_HP + H_S_Recover - H_S_Load + EH == H_Demand + DHW_Demand, #The Demand of Heat and DHW needs to be satisfied at each timestep
             
             
             H_S.dt() == H_S_Load - H_S_Recover/eff_H_S, #Loading and recovery of the Heat Storage
             
             H_S_Load * H_S_Recover == 0, #It is not allowed to Load and Recover at the same Time, at least one of both needs to be equal to '0' at each Timestep
             
             
             # The maximal Value of the Enery System Components is the Upper Bound for the Value at each time Step
             
             P_el_HP1 <= P_el_HP_max,
             P_el_HP1 >= 0.3*P_el_HP_max, # the Heat Pump is a variable speed heat Pump and has a minimal output of 40% of the nominal Power
             H_S <= H_S_max,
             B_S <= B_S_max,
             EH <= EH_max,])

#Binary Variable to tell the Program that it only needs to Pay the "Fix Costs" for the Component if the Components have a  Value greater than 0
BS_bin=m.if2(-B_S_max,1,0) #Battery Storage
HS_bin=m.if2(-H_S_max,1,0) #Heat Storage
HP_bin=m.if2(-P_el_HP_max,1,0) # Heat Pump
EH_bin=m.if2(-EH_max,1,0) #Electrical Heater

#Objective is to minimize the cost of the Energy System (the Cost of Components that only need to be bought once get divided by the number of timesteps)
Objective=((2599.3*HP_bin+1142.9*P_el_HP_max*COP_HP+(EH_max*50)+1234.8*BS_bin+792.8*B_S_max+(((H_S_max*3600)/(4.18*(45-20)))*1.6+672.5*HS_bin))/(20*timesteps)-0.05*I_Excess+0.35*(I_feed_out))
           

m.Minimize(Objective)

m.solve(disp=True)


#Print Results

print("Nominal Power of the Heat Pump=",max(P_el_HP),"kW")
print("maximum Capacity of the Heat Storage=",max(H_S),"kW")
print("Volume of the Heat Storage=", max(Vol_HS),"m^3")
print("maximum Capacity of the Battery", max(B_S),"kW")
print("Electricity from the Public Grid",sum(I_feed_out[0:timesteps-1]))


# Plot results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(5, 5.1), sharex=True)
axes = axes.ravel()

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t, EL_Demand, 'r-', label='Electrical Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, PV_P,'b:', label='PV Production',lw=1) #z.B. Generator (haben wir aber in unserem Energiesystem nicht)


ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(t, EL_Demand, 'r-', label='Electrical Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,I_feed_out, 'k--', label='Electricity from the public Grid',lw=1)

ax = axes[2]
ax.plot(t,B_S.value, 'k-', label='Battery Storage',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,B_S_Load,'g--',label='Battery Storage Loading',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,B_S_Recover,'b:',label='Battery Storage Recovery',lw=1) #lw=2 --> linewidth

ax = axes[3]
ax.plot(t,H_Demand, 'r-', label='Heat Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, Q_HP.value,'b:',\
        label='Thermal Production Heat Pump',lw=1)

ax = axes[4]
ax.plot(t,H_S, 'k-', label='Heat Storage',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,H_S_Load,'g--',label='Heat Storage Loading',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,H_S_Recover.value,'b:',\
        label='Heat Storage Recovered Energy',lw=1)


ax = axes[5]
ax.plot(t,DHW_Demand, 'r-', label='Domestic Hot Water Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, EH,'b:',\
        label='Electrical Water Heater',lw=1)




for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='center left',\
              bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),frameon=False)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xlim(0,len(t)-1)

plt.savefig('Results.png', dpi=600,\
            bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Gekko solvers are numerical so values of `1e-8` and `-1e-8` are equivalent according to solver tolerance. This means that `<` and `<=` are the same for a numerical solver. Try setting the switching point slightly away from zero to get the intended effect of setting `BS_bin=0` when `B_S_max<tol`.

```py
tol = 0.1
BS_bin=m.if3(-B_S_max+tol,1,0) #Battery Storage
HS_bin=m.if3(-H_S_max+tol,1,0) #Heat Storage
HP_bin=m.if3(-P_el_HP_max+tol,1,0) # Heat Pump
EH_bin=m.if3(-EH_max+tol,1,0) #Electrical Heater
```

The `m.if3()` functions add a new binary variable for each function at every time step so the problem can get very large.

Additionally, the `m.sos1()` function is only needed when the discrete variable choices are not continuous (e.g. `[0,2,7,10]`) or when they are not integers (e.g. `[0,0.2,0.6,1.5]`). Try using a binary variable instead:

```py
# Binary Variable for Heat Pump
#  it can either be turned on '1' or off '0'
b_HP = m.MV(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
b_HP.STATUS = 1
P_HP_Binary=HP_Bit*b_HP  #m.sos1([0,1])
```

The prior version of the model had `P_HP_Binary.STATUS = 1`. This is only needed for `m.MV()` or `m.CV()` types to turn them on or off.

The feedback status on the `m.SV()` variables (e.g `EH.FSTATUS=1`, `P_el_HP1.FSTATUS=1`, and `I_feed_out.FSTATUS=1`) are only needed when there is a measurement for these values and you want to update the initial condition. This is sometimes used in MPC applications, but it isn't needed here.

The successful solution is:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    3.01009999999951      sec
 Objective      :    174.293488846257     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

Nominal Power of the Heat Pump= 0.0 kW
maximum Capacity of the Heat Storage= 0.0 kW
Volume of the Heat Storage= 0.0 m^3
maximum Capacity of the Battery 0.0 kW
Electricity from the Public Grid 426.5910395607
```

[image: results]

However, this doesn't seem like a correct solution to have zero capacity for everything and just buy from the grid. Here is the full script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timesteps= 100
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
t = np.linspace(0, timesteps-1, timesteps) #Zeit
m.time = t

m.options.SOLVER = 1 
m.options.IMODE = 6 
m.options.NODES = 2 
m.options.REDUCE=3
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1.0e-1',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'objective_convergence_tolerance 1.0e-4',\
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 100',\
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.1']

# Energy Demand

    #1. electricity
    
EL_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.9200000,
 1.4890000,1.4920000,1.1300000,0.64099997,0.58600003,
 0.58399999,0.61000001,0.54900002,0.59500003,0.92699999,
 0.95599997,0.91000003,1.1450000,1.1090000,1.6360000,
 1.4740000,1.4680001,2.6150000,2.1810000,1.2320000,
 1.3700000,0.96899998,1.3220000,1.1880000,0.64399999,
 0.53899997,0.55299997,0.52899998,0.56099999,0.54600000,
 0.80000001,1.1350000,0.70700002,1.1680000,1.0440000,
 2.3160000,1.6420000,2.2370000,2.8870001,1.8550000,
 1.4030000,0.70599997,1.4980000,3.4879999,1.5130000,
 1.4349999,1.3520000,1.0530000,0.51700002,0.55000001,
 0.52800000,0.52999997,0.56199998,0.53700000,0.58999997,
 0.53500003,0.92500001,1.3490000,0.66299999,4.3810000,
 1.0200000,0.79799998,0.77899998,1.0840000,2.1530001,
 3.7449999,5.3490000,1.8710001,2.3610001,0.78799999,
 0.47099999,0.56800002,0.51700002,0.54799998,0.55699998,
 0.51400000,0.56500000,3.2790000,2.2750001,1.2300000,
 0.97899997,0.78200001,1.0140001,0.77800000,0.58099997,
 0.52999997,0.55900002,1.1770000,1.5400000,1.4349999,
 2.0400000,2.2790000,1.6520000,1.6450000,1.2830000,
 0.55800003,0.52499998,0.51899999,0.53799999])
EL_Demand_Arr2=EL_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
EL_Demand_Arr=EL_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

EL_Demand=m.Param(EL_Demand_Arr,name='EL_Demand')
    
    #2. heat
    
H_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.0960000,1.0790000,
 1.1590000,1.1760000,1.6940000,2.2639999,2.1450000,
 2.0769999,2.0720000,2.0300000,1.9069999,1.8810000,
 1.7880000,1.8180000,1.8049999,2.0430000,2.1489999,
 2.1700001,2.1830001,2.1910000,1.9920000,1.5290000,
 1.1810000,1.0400000,1.4310000,1.4110000,1.4700000,
 1.4900000,1.8880000,2.4530001,2.2809999,2.3199999,
 2.2960000,2.3299999,2.1630001,2.1289999,2.0599999,
 2.1090000,2.0940001,2.3450000,2.4380000,2.4679999,
 2.4630001,2.4480000,2.2219999,1.8480000,1.5779999,
 1.4310000,1.5000000,1.4790000,1.5410000,1.5620000,
 1.9790000,2.5720000,2.3910000,2.4319999,2.4070001,
 2.4430001,2.2679999,2.2309999,2.1589999,2.2110000,
 2.1949999,2.4579999,2.5560000,2.5869999,2.5820000,
 2.5660000,2.3290000,1.9380000,1.6540000,1.5000000,
 1.7160000,1.6930000,1.7630000,1.7869999,2.2650001,
 2.9430001,2.7360001,2.7839999,2.7539999,2.7950001,
 2.5950000,2.5539999,2.4710000,2.5300000,2.5120001,
 2.8130000,2.9250000,2.9600000,2.9549999,2.9370000,
 2.6659999,2.2170000,1.8930000,1.7160000,1.7980000,
 1.7670000,1.8789999,1.9160000])
H_Demand_Arr2=H_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
H_Demand_Arr=H_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

H_Demand=m.Param(H_Demand_Arr,name='H_Demand')
    
    #3. Domestic Hot Water
    
DHW_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.7420000,0,0,2.0320001,
 0,0,3.7739999,2.4960001,3.3670001,0,2.4380000,
 1.1030000,0,0,0,3.1350000,2.2060001,0,4.4120002,
 0,0,0,0.87099999,1.5089999,0,0,0,0,0,0.87099999,
 0.81300002,1.1610000,2.5539999,1.6260000,0,0,
 0.63900000,0,3.4830000,2.8450000,2.4960001,
 7.1409998,5.7480001,2.3800001,3.1930001,0,1.1610000,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.6129999,1.9160000,4.2379999,
 0.34799999,5.4569998,0,0,2.8450000,0,0,0,0,0,
 2.4960001,1.6260000,0,2.5539999,0,0,0,0,0,
 1.6260000,0,3.0190001,0,2.8450000,1.1030000,
 2.9030001,0,0,0,0.98699999,0,1.1610000,0.34799999,
 1.3930000,1.2770000,4.4120002,0,0,0,0,1.8580000,
 0,0.98699999])
DHW_Demand_Arr2=DHW_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
DHW_Demand_Arr=DHW_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

DHW_Demand=m.Param(DHW_Demand_Arr,name='TWW_BED')
    
    #4. electricity production from PV
    
PV_P_Arr1=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.057000000,
 0.14399999,0.30500001,0.13600001,0.28900000,0.22000000,
 0.0040000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0.061999999,0.78899997,0.56300002,0.13600001,
 0.052999999,0.017000001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0.037000000,0.098999999,0.15000001,
 0.11200000,0,0.12600000,0.032000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0040000002,0.73600000,1.8250000,
 2.4020000,3.1870000,0.66500002,0.045000002,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
PV_P_Arr2=PV_P_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
PV_P_Arr=PV_P_Arr2[0:timesteps]

PV_P=m.Param(PV_P_Arr,name='PV_P')
    
# Heat Pump "Bit" ist '1' during the Heating Season and '0' outside the heating Season to tell the Promgram that the Heat Pump may only be used during heating Season

HP_Bit_Arr1=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
HP_Bit_Arr=HP_Bit_Arr1[0:timesteps]

HP_Bit=m.Param(HP_Bit_Arr,name='HP_Bit')   


# Battery Storage

B_S = m.SV(0,lb=0) 
B_S.FSTATUS=1
m.fix_initial(B_S,0)

B_S_Load = m.SV(0,lb=0) #Loading Battery
B_S_Recover = m.SV(0,lb=0) #Recover Energy from Batterie

eff_B_S = 0.95 #efficiency Battery


# Heat Storage

H_S = m.SV(0,lb=0) 
H_S.FSTATUS=1
m.fix_initial(H_S,0)

H_S_Load = m.SV(lb=0)    #Loading Heat Storage
H_S_Recover = m.SV(lb=0) #Recover Energy from Heat Storage

eff_H_S = 0.9 #efficiency Heat Storage

#Heat Pump

# Binary Variable for Heat Pump
#  it can either be turned on '1' or off '0'
b_HP = m.MV(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
b_HP.STATUS = 1
P_HP_Binary=HP_Bit*b_HP  #m.sos1([0,1])
P_HP_Binary.STATUS = 1 

#Electrical sizing of the Heat Pump

P_el_HP1= m.SV(0,lb=0)
#P_el_HP1.FSTATUS=1

#Electrical Water Heater

EH=m.SV(0,lb=0)
#EH.FSTATUS=1

# The Power of the Heat Pump multiplied with
#    the Binary Variable gives the actual 
#    Output of the Heat Pump

P_el_HP=m.Intermediate(P_HP_Binary*P_el_HP1)

P_el_HP_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Heat Pump
P_el_HP_max.STATUS=1

H_S_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Heat Storage
H_S_max.STATUS=1

B_S_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Battery
B_S_max.STATUS=1

EH_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Electrical Water Heater
EH_max.STATUS=1


COP_HP=3.5 #COP of the Heat Pump

#Modulating Heat Pump
Q_HP=m.Intermediate(1.4*COP_HP*0.3*P_el_HP_max* \
 P_HP_Binary+(COP_HP*(1-0.3*1.4)/(1-0.3)) \
 *(P_el_HP-0.3*P_el_HP_max*P_HP_Binary)) 

# thermal Energy Output of the Heat Pump
#Q_HP=m.Intermediate(COP_HP*P_el_HP) 

# the objective of this Optimization is to minimize
# the Cost for the Energy-System, since you only 
# Pay for the maximal Value of the Heat Pump, 
# Energy Storage and the electrical Water Heater
# and not for the value at each timestep, I define
# a FV that describes the maximal Value of the Components

#Losses of the Heat Storage
# eps_HS = 0.9 # Heat Storage Efficiancy
# Vol_HS=m.Intermediate((H_S_max*3600)/(1000*4.18*(45-20)))
# Vol_HS_timestep=m.Intermediate((H_S*3600)/(1000*4.18*(45-20)))
# alpha_a=8 #W/m^2K
# s=0.1 #m
# Lamda= 0.03 #W/mK
# r_i=0.3
# r_a=r_i+0.1
# A_Top_Bottom=2*pi*r_a**2
# U_Top_Bottom=(1/((1/alpha_a)+(s/Lamda))) #annahme, keine Konvektion an der Innenseite also alpha_i=0
# U_A_Surface=(((Vol_HS_timestep/(r_i**2))/(((1/Lamda)\
#   *np.log(r_a/r_i))+(1/(alpha_a*r_a)))))

#Q_Losses_HS=m.Intermediate((U_Top_Bottom*A_Top_Bottom*2+U_A_Surface)*(45-20)/1000)

# We have energy Production from PV, there ist a possibility to give Energy thats not needed to the public Grid

I_Excess=m.Var(0,lb=0)

# In Case we have more Demand for Electrical Enery than Production from PV we have the possibility to get Energy from the public Grid

I_feed_out=m.SV(0,lb=0)
#I_feed_out.FSTATUS=1

# Volume of the Heat Storage in m^3

Vol_HS=m.Intermediate((H_S_max*3600)/(1000*4.18*(45-20)))

# boundary conditions 
m.Equations([PV_P +I_feed_out + B_S_Recover - P_el_HP - B_S_Load - I_Excess - EH == EL_Demand, #Energy Balance needs to satisfy the Demand
             B_S.dt() == B_S_Load - B_S_Recover/eff_B_S, #Loading and Recovery of the Battery
             B_S_Load * B_S_Recover == 0, #It is not allowed to Load and Recover at the same Time, at least one of both needs to be equal to '0' at each Timestep
             Q_HP + H_S_Recover - H_S_Load + EH == H_Demand + DHW_Demand, #The Demand of Heat and DHW needs to be satisfied at each timestep
             H_S.dt() == H_S_Load - H_S_Recover/eff_H_S, #Loading and recovery of the Heat Storage
             H_S_Load * H_S_Recover == 0, #It is not allowed to Load and Recover at the same Time, at least one of both needs to be equal to '0' at each Timestep
             # The maximal Value of the Enery System Components is the Upper Bound for the Value at each time Step
             P_el_HP1 <= P_el_HP_max,
             P_el_HP1 >= 0.3*P_el_HP_max, # the Heat Pump is a variable speed heat Pump and has a minimal output of 40% of the nominal Power
             H_S <= H_S_max,
             B_S <= B_S_max,
             EH <= EH_max])

#Binary Variable to tell the Program that it only needs to Pay the "Fix Costs" for the Component if the Components have a  Value greater than 0
tol = 0.01
BS_bin=m.if3(-B_S_max+tol,1,0) #Battery Storage
HS_bin=m.if3(-H_S_max+tol,1,0) #Heat Storage
HP_bin=m.if3(-P_el_HP_max+tol,1,0) # Heat Pump
EH_bin=m.if3(-EH_max+tol,1,0) #Electrical Heater

#Objective is to minimize the cost of the Energy System (the Cost of Components that only need to be bought once get divided by the number of timesteps)
Objective=((2599.3*HP_bin+1142.9*P_el_HP_max*COP_HP+(EH_max*50)+1234.8*BS_bin+792.8*B_S_max+(((H_S_max*3600)/(4.18*(45-20)))*1.6+672.5*HS_bin))/(20*timesteps)-0.05*I_Excess+0.35*(I_feed_out))
           

m.Minimize(Objective)

m.solve(disp=True)


#Print Results

print("Nominal Power of the Heat Pump=",max(P_el_HP),"kW")
print("maximum Capacity of the Heat Storage=",max(H_S),"kW")
print("Volume of the Heat Storage=", max(Vol_HS),"m^3")
print("maximum Capacity of the Battery", max(B_S),"kW")
print("Electricity from the Public Grid",sum(I_feed_out[0:timesteps-1]))


# Plot results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(5, 5.1), sharex=True)
axes = axes.ravel()

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t, EL_Demand, 'r-', label='Electrical Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, PV_P,'b:', label='PV Production',lw=1) #z.B. Generator (haben wir aber in unserem Energiesystem nicht)


ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(t, EL_Demand, 'r-', label='Electrical Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,I_feed_out, 'k--', label='Electricity from the public Grid',lw=1)

ax = axes[2]
ax.plot(t,B_S.value, 'k-', label='Battery Storage',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,B_S_Load,'g--',label='Battery Storage Loading',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,B_S_Recover,'b:',label='Battery Storage Recovery',lw=1) #lw=2 --> linewidth

ax = axes[3]
ax.plot(t,H_Demand, 'r-', label='Heat Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, Q_HP.value,'b:',\
        label='Thermal Production Heat Pump',lw=1)

ax = axes[4]
ax.plot(t,H_S, 'k-', label='Heat Storage',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,H_S_Load,'g--',label='Heat Storage Loading',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,H_S_Recover.value,'b:',\
        label='Heat Storage Recovered Energy',lw=1)


ax = axes[5]
ax.plot(t,DHW_Demand, 'r-', label='Domestic Hot Water Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, EH,'b:',\
        label='Electrical Water Heater',lw=1)




for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='center left',\
              bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),frameon=False)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xlim(0,len(t)-1)

plt.savefig('Results.png', dpi=600,\
            bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

If you have an idea for a better solution, try setting `.STATUS=0` and insert the value that *may* be better as a test. If it is feasible and the objective function is lower, then there may be multiple local minima. This is unlikely if the problem is a mixed integer linear programming (MILP) problem. Below are example tests.

**Increase Heat Pump Capacity**

Objective increases (worse solution) to 456.39.

```py
P_el_HP_max=m.FV(value=1.0,lb=0) #Heat Pump
P_el_HP_max.STATUS=0
```

**Increase Heat Storage**

Objective increases (worse solution) to 208.49.

```py
H_S_max=m.FV(value=1.0,lb=0) #Heat Storage
H_S_max.STATUS=0
```

**Increase Battery Storage**

Objective increases (worse solution) to 308.09.

```py
H_S_max=m.FV(value=1.0,lb=0) #Heat Storage
H_S_max.STATUS=0
```

**Set Electrical Water Heater Capacity**

No feasible solution found. Optimal capacity is 9.609 kW. Anything lower appears to be infeasible.

```py
EH_max=m.FV(value=1,lb=0) #Electrical Water Heater
EH_max.STATUS=0
```

I haven't tried manually setting the heat pump on or off, but all of the capacity design variable appear to worsen the objective function. The exception is the Electrical Water Heater max capacity that is 9.609 kW. It appears from this study and model that the original strategy to buy all electricity from the grid and solely use an electrical water heater is optimal.